# Open a workbook from Sharepoint & get worksheet / array from it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get an array from a worksheet in a workbook located on Sharepoint.

```
Public Sub PushintoDB()
    Dim requestID As String
    Dim version As String
    Dim mapping As ListObject
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim dest As Workbook
    Dim weekly As Workbook
    Dim bidDB As ListObject
    Dim bidID As String
    Dim followup As ListObject
    Dim SummaryWB As Workbook
    Dim map As ListObject
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set weekly = Workbooks.Open("URL", 0, ReadOnly:=True)
   'Set source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Options")
   'Set dest = Workbooks.Open("URL",0,ReadOnly:=True)
    Set mapping = weekly.Worksheets("Mapping").ListObjects("Mapping")
    Set followup = weekly.Worksheets("follow-up").ListObjects("followup")
   'Set bidDB = dest.Worksheets("Bid-DB").ListObjects("BidDB")
```

The URL is correct, so are the names of the worksheet and array, but
mapping doesn't get the weekly reference. Instead, it gives me the error

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Nor does it work with `dest` and the correct URL but it **does** work with `source`, which is the workbook where the code is.

How can I open and work with the workbook from a Sharepoint location?

Comment: does the "weekly" workbook open in the first place?

Comment: It does, and it appears on the VBAProject board. I noticed that there is no worksheets or modules to be found when opened like this, so i guess this is where the problem lies.